# Fatal error: Declaration of EasyBlogTableMediaManager::bind() must be compatible with that of JTableInterface::bind()

Tags: php, joomla, easyblog

I have a problem with `easyblog`. When I try to open a blog entry through backend I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Declaration of EasyBlogTableMediaManager::bind() must be compatible with that of JTableInterface::bind() in /home/mysit/public_html/localadvertiser/administrator/components/com_easyblog/tables/mediamanager.php on line 46

I am running `Joomla 3.2.5`
The error reporting is set to 'maximum'. Any idea what the issue could be here?

This is file where the error occurs

```
class EasyBlogTableMediaManager extends EasyBlogTable
{
    var $id     = null;
    var $path   = '';
    var $type   = '';
    var $params = '';
    function __construct(& $db )
    {
        parent::__construct( '#__easyblog_mediamanager' , 'id' , $db );
    }
    public function bind( $data = array() )
    {
        return parent::bind( $data );
    }
    public function load( $path , $type )
    {
        $db     = EasyBlogHelper::db();
        $query  = 'SELECT * FROM ' . EasyBlogHelper::getHelper( 'SQL' )->nameQuote( $this->_tbl );
        $query  .= ' WHERE ' . EasyBlogHelper::getHelper( 'SQL' )->nameQuote( 'path' ) . '=' . $db->Quote( $path );
        $query  .= ' AND ' . EasyBlogHelper::getHelper( 'SQL' )->nameQuote( 'type' ) . '=' . $db->Quote( $type );
        $db->setQuery( $query );
        $obj    = $db->loadObject();
        return parent::bind( $obj );
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, try posting the code in line 46 of the file mentioned in your error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TLDR

Yes I think the error is occurring because you have error reporting set to maximum, which is probably forcing a [`STRICT`](http://php.net/manual/en/migrating5.errorrep.php) mode, if you set the level to `None` it should work fine, as this will set `display_errors` to **0**. This is also, probably, an indication you're using PHP 5.4 or higher on your server (***A Good Thing***™).

#### Longer & more precise:

As the error states the `Declaration of EasyBlogTableMediaManager::bind()` **must** be compatible (i.e. the same/match) with the original declaration in the `JTableInterface` class.

This tells us that `EasyBlogTableMediaManager` which extends `EasyBlogTable` has as a parent class going back to `JTable` (found at `/libraries/joomla/table/table.php`) which is defined as:

```
abstract class JTable extends JObject implements JObservableInterface, JTableInterface
```

You will notice that it implements `JTableInterface`, which means that the original `JTable->bind()` must match the [interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) declaration of `JTableInterface` (found at `/libraries/joomla/table/interface.php`) you will see that it's defined in the interface file as:

```
public function bind($src, $ignore = array());
```

When you compare that to the declaration in the `EasyBlogTableMediaManager` class you've provided:

```
public function bind( $data = array() )
{
    return parent::bind( $data );
}
```

You can see the method signatures are different (i.e. the EasyBlog `bind()` method is only defining a single parameter `$data`). So, quoting the PHP documentation for **interface** linked previously:

> Note: The class implementing the interface must use the **exact same
>   method signatures** as are defined in the interface. Not doing so will
>   result in a fatal error.

Between Joomla 2.5.x and Joomla 3.x several method signatures changed, given that it's a [major version number change](http://semver.org) this is to be expected and developers can produce separate extension builds for each version to avoid this issue but it does introduce an extra layer of support.

#### If you need Error Reporting on `Maximum`

You may be able to fix it by simply changing the method signature to this:

```
public function bind( $data = array(), $ignore = array())
{
    return parent::bind( $data );
}
```

However, that may result in the error moving further up the class hierarchy, and will probably re-appear if you update the version of EasyBlog (as your change will be over-written). It's probably best to take it up with the [developer of EasyBlog](http://stackideas.com).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!
I used the following code

```
    public function bind( $data = array(), $ignore = array())
{
    return parent::bind( $data );
}
```

Which gave a [standards violation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423494/why-is-overriding-method-parameters-a-violation-of-strict-standards-in-php)

In order to fix this I needed to make the following changes to the load function's declaration by adding additional parameters to the EasyBlogTableMediaManager class -

```
public function load($path = '' , $type = '' ,   $keys = null, $reset = true )
```