# PHP Override Interface signature in child class

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, signature

I have the following interface / classes:

```
class Part {}
class Engine extends Part{}

interface CarsInterface {
    public function selectTimeLine(Part $object);
}

abstract class Car implements CarsInterface {}

class Hybrid extends Car {
    public function selectTimeLine(Engine $object) {}
}
```

Why can't i use Engine object in the child signature (Hybrid Class) if Engine is sub-class of "Part" (I know its possible in Java...)

What is the proper way to achieve this functionality in PHP?
Thx

Comment: There's a few questions that address this. This one seems the most promising, suggests using instanceof: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/227766/changing-method-signature-for-implementing-classes-in-php Here's one on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423494/why-is-overriding-method-parameters-a-violation-of-strict-standards-in-php Your best bet is probably to remove the type from the argument declaration and use `instanceof`.

Comment: @MontgomeryJean I saw the second answer while looking around...but can you elaborate on "instanceof" can you give an example?

Comment: nevermind...saw it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, PHP is sucks. =)

If I'm not mistaken, you need something like:

```
interface SomeInterface {
}

class Part implements SomeInterface  {}
class Engine extends Part implements SomeInterface{}

interface CarsInterface {
    public function selectTimeLine(SomeInterface $object);
}

abstract class Car implements CarsInterface {}

class Hybrid extends Car {
    public function selectTimeLine(SomeInterface $object) {}
}
```

Comment: Since `Part` implements `SomeInterface` and `Engine` extends `Part` the `Engine` object will also implement `SomeInterface` see my example and for test case http://ideone.com/6CNdhk.

Answer (score 1):

In short an interface is meant to provide you with those restrictions by setting specific instructions for your objects. This way when checking on the object's capabilities or with `instanceof` you can always expect to receive what was specified.

There is no "proper" way to achieve what you are wanting to do, but the suggested method is to type-hint with interfaces as opposed to specific class definitions.

This way you can always guarantee the available methods for the provided objects.

```
interface TimeLineInterface { }

class Part implements TimeLineInterface { }

class Engine extends Part { }

interface CarInterface
{
    public function selectTimeLine(TimeLineInterface $object);
}

abstract class Car implements CarInterface { }

class Hybrid extends Car
{
   public function selectTimeLine(TimeLineInterface $object) { }
}
```

if you want to force the acceptance of a specific type of object for the object's method you would need to check the object instance like so.

```
class Hybrid extends Car
{
   public function selectTimeLine(TimeLineInterface $object) 
   {
       if (!$object instanceof Engine) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(__CLASS__ . '::' . __FUNCTION__ . ' expects an instance of Engine. Received ' . get_class($object));
       }
   }
}
```