# How to override a parents class method and change params?

Tags: php

I'm extending a class:

```
class Foo extends Bar
```

I have a method that overrides a method on the parent class:

```
myMethod($param1, $param2)
```

I now wish to add an extra param in my child class, but I get a compatibility error. eg.

```
myMethod($param1, $param2, $param3)
```

What's the correct way to override a parent's class method so I can change the params?

Please note I am unable to change the parent class in any way.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423494/why-is-overriding-method-parameters-a-violation-of-strict-standards-in-php) SO question.

Comment: you could use an optional parameter? PHP Doesn't support overloading, it does it by allowing optional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the parent class what about add a `setParam3($param3) and getParam3()` methods, so before to call `myMethod` call `setParam3` and then in your child class

```
myMethod($param1, $param2)
{
    $param3 = $this->getparam3();
    // rest of code
}
```