# PHP Intelephense - Method is not compatible with child method

Tags: php, intelephense

Consider the following two classes:

```
class A {
   ...

   testMethod($param = null) {
       ...
   }
}

class B extends A {
   ...

   testMethod($additionalParam, $param = null) {
      ... do something with $additionalParam ...
      parent::testMethod($param);
   }
}
```

`intelephense` is raising me an error, that the two methods are not compatible (they are indeed not). My script although runs fine, nonetheless.

Could someone explain to me, why would `intelephense` be bothered by this design? Wouldn't this design be considered valid? If not, if I would like to extend a method in a sub class, by storing additional information, which I didn't store in the base class, how should I proceed?

Comment: I think [Why is overriding method parameters a violation of strict standards in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423494/why-is-overriding-method-parameters-a-violation-of-strict-standards-in-php) explains a lot about why this is a problem. There are also links in there to other bits.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot possible overwrite same method with diff parameters, for this try change the name `testMethod` to `testMethodMain` or another name in your class `B`.